# SQL: How to combine results of multiple columns using where like

Tags: sql

Simple, I want combine results when using WHERE LIKE in multiple columns

```
$query = "SELECT T.Id_Servicio ids, 
            C.Nombre cliente, 
            T.T_Atencion atencion, 
            M.Nombre marca, 
            P.Nombre producto, 
            SU.Nombre subproducto, 
            T.Observaciones obs, 
            T.Estado edo
            FROM t_servicio T
            INNER JOIN cat_clientes C ON C.Id = T.Id_Cliente
            INNER JOIN cat_marcas M ON M.Id = T.Marca
            INNER JOIN cat_productos P ON P.Id = T.Producto
            INNER JOIN cat_subproducto SU ON SU.Id = T.SubProducto
            WHERE C.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR T.T_Atencion LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR M.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR P.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR SU.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'";
```

With this instruction, take last results but doesn't combine all results, which would be the correct statement?

I hope can help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INNER JOIN` you will only match those row that are related.
If I get you right, simple switching to `LEFT JOIN` will make you happier.
You also **may** need to have a `GROUP BY` statement in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT T.Id_Servicio ids, 
            C.Nombre cliente, 
            T.T_Atencion atencion, 
            M.Nombre marca, 
            P.Nombre producto, 
            SU.Nombre subproducto, 
            T.Observaciones obs, 
            T.Estado edo
            FROM t_servicio T
            LEFT JOIN cat_clientes C ON C.Id = T.Id_Cliente
            LEFT JOIN cat_marcas M ON M.Id = T.Marca
            LEFT JOIN cat_productos P ON P.Id = T.Producto
            LEFT JOIN cat_subproducto SU ON SU.Id = T.SubProducto
            WHERE C.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR T.T_Atencion LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR M.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR P.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
            OR SU.Nombre LIKE '%$termsearch%'
```

and what are you comparing to????
I assume that $termsearch is the entire string you want to search in SU.Nombre

Comment: $termsearch is the term or text obtained from the input text, i will try!

Answer (score 0):

LIKE '%$termsearch%' should be LIKE '%' + @termsearch + '%'